# How to fly IFR to an airport without any instrument approaches?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules

Would I just file an IFR flight plan to the airport in question, and expect to be cleared for the visual approach if there are no instrument approaches at the destination airport?

Comment: Maybe by filing a Y flightplan.

Comment: You can end your IFR flight at any point and switch to VFR.

Comment: In the US, when you file, you must include an alternate that satisfies the requirements of §91.169  e.g Precision 600 and 2, non-precision 800 and 2, no approach—visibility minima are those allowing descent from the MEA, approach, and landing under basic VFR.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If the airport in question has no operating control tower you need to cancel your ifr flight plan after landing if you choose to not do it in flight.  Once you land you can cancel with air traffic contol, if you are able to establish radio communication, or cancel with a flight service station.  It is usually going to be easiest to cancel with the local approach controller in flight, if there is no operating tower.  Remember all ifr traffic, landing and departing, will not be able to receive their approach clearance or ifr release until you cancel.